# How to handle invalid method [x] for action [y] errors in Struts2?

Tags: exception, struts2

I am using Struts 2.3 and I have dynamic method invocation turned on as well as `strict-method-invocation="true"` on packages.

The problem is that if the user tries to invoke a method that does not exist or isn't allowed on an action he gets ugly message.

I would like to display my own custom error page for that.

I tried to setup a global exception handler like that:

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/WEB-INF/ErrorPage.html</result>
</global-results>
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

This works when I throw some exception from one of my action classes, but it does not handle Strut's "Invalid method x for action y" errors.

Comment: You should not use DMI, it's discouraged in the recent versions and turned off by default.

Comment: DMI it's not only discouraged and turned off by default, in recent versions it can NOT be turned on. Keep using it means that you can't upgrade to any Struts2 version higher than 2.3.20, so if a security bug is found and a fix released, you won't be able to patch your project. Unless it is a very old legacy project (then who cares about the error message), I strongly suggest you to spend one hour (or day, or week, it doesn't matter as long as you are concerned with security) to completely remove DMI from the project.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: You can turn it on in the latest S2. Also there is some work in progress - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4540. Agree on the other parts.

Comment: @AleksandrM not sure why I remembered it was deprecated on >= 2.3.24... BTW, it's a shame they didn't :S

Answer (score 1):

*Relatively hacky solution.* Since using not allowed method with strict DMI results in response with a 404 status code, you can use `<error-page>` to map it to some page in web.xml file.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If you want to execute some action instead of just showing some page you can send redirect from this page.

```
<% response.sendRedirect("some_action"); %>
```